# What does + before \\ do?

Tags: line-breaking

In Grätzer's *More Math Into LaTeX*, 5th Edition, the chapter on books shows a master document that includes at its end the following lines:

```
\appendix+\\
\include{AppendixA}%Math symbol tables+\\
... +\\
\backmatter+\\
\printindex+\\
\end{document}+\\[8pt]
```

What is the purpose of the `+\\` there?

Here is an extract of the above section from the book, with the `+\\` highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link or a screen-grab?

Comment: I think it's a leftover of some formatting instruction; it seems that some coding went wrong.

Comment: Reminds my of `Doxygen` codes

Comment: Highlighted in red: http://i.imgur.com/F8K5OBj.png @Werner

Comment: There is no ` +\\ ` in the 4th Edition.

Comment: Is the trailing \\ probably also a formatting artifact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no logical reason why this should be part of the code, especially since [anything after `\end{document}` is disregarded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28499/5764), making

```
\end{document}+\\[8pt]
```

seem arbitrarily misplaced.

The assumption is that this may be an artifact from editing, as [it does not exist in the 4th edition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317970/what-does-before-do?noredirect=1#comment776530_317970).

Comment: To be more precise, all ``+\\`` are to be removed. For instance, `\appendix` should never be followed by ``\\`` (and ``\\`` is not recommended in the other places it appears).