# The frames did not generate for unknown reason how to make frames?

Tags: beamer

here is my code while the 2nd slide does not generates. why?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}


\title{Bipass on earth}

\author{M. H. Loi}
\institute{University of South}
\date{Oct 19, 2016}


\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}


\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub a}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\end{document}` ends the compilation of your file, as [anything after `\end{document}` is ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28499/5764). My guess is you mistakenly used

```
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

to denote a single frame showing the title. Since there are two ways of presenting a frame - one via the `\frame` *command* and another via the `frame` *environment*, perhaps you though `\end{document}` meant `\end{frame}`. But if you use the `\frame` *command* to set a frame, there is no need for `\end{frame}`.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{Bipass on earth}

\author{M. H. Loi}
\institute{University of South}
\date{Oct 19, 2016}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
%\end{document} % < ---------- ...this should not be here.

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub a}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document} % < ---------- ...it should probably be here.
```